# Transformation of an equation with a fraction in the numerator of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Can someone explain the steps here -- how does it get the second part where it is equals to $20$? I was confused because of the fraction $1/2$ in the numerator.

I am studying some examples but I don't understand this one.
\begin{gather*}
\frac{(1/2)x}{21} + \frac{(1/2)x}{24} = 10\\
\frac{x}{21} + \frac{x}{24} = 20\\
15 x = 168 \times 20
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Given:

$$\dfrac{(1/2)x}{21}+ \dfrac {(1/2)x}{24} = 10$$

2) We have the same equation as:

$$\dfrac{0.5x}{21}+\dfrac{0.5x}{24} = 10$$

3) To get: $$\dfrac{x}{21}+\dfrac{x}{24} = 20$$

4) Simply multiply the entire equation in step 2) by 2:

$$2\left(\dfrac{0.5x}{21}+\dfrac{0.5x}{24} = 10\right)$$

5) We are left with:
$$\dfrac{x}{21}+\dfrac{x}{24} = 20$$

Comment: Now, that's easy to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 
$$
\frac{(1/2)x}{21}+\frac{(1/2)x}{24}=10
$$
then you can take a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ out the front of the left-hand side
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{21}+\frac{x}{24}\right)=10
$$
and then multiply both sides of the equation by $2$
$$
\frac{x}{21}+\frac{x}{24}=20
$$